# Minimum sample sizes needed for a series of allowed errors, given a required accuracy and required confidence

Tags: statistics

I need a formula that will calculate the minimum sample sizes needed for a series of allowed errors, given a required accuracy and required confidence.  My samples will be either pass or fail.  There are no retries.

Another way of saying it is that I'm given an accuracy of 99.90% and a confidence of 80% that I must meet.  If I allow zero errors then I need to know my minimum sample size.  If I allow one error then I need to know that minimum sample size.  If I allow two errors then I need to know that minimum sample size, and so on.

I'm looking for something of this nature:
Enter Required Accuracy:  99.90%
Enter Required Confidence: 80%
Enter Allowed Errors: 0  |  Return Minimum Sample Size 1,609
Enter Allowed Errors: 1  |  Return Minimum Sample Size 2,994
Enter Allowed Errors: 2  |  Return Minimum Sample Size 4,278
Enter Allowed Errors...  and so on

Right now I'm using the BINOMDIST function in Excel for the calculations.  Using a brute force method I fill-down the BINOMDIST function in a column to provide me with the probability/confidence that my accuracy requirement will be met for a given sample size and given number of errors. This allows me to then perform a lookup on the sample size where the probability/confidence I'm looking has been met (by the BINOMDIST formula).  It's brute force.  It results in a huge Excel file that is slow to calculate.  But it works perfectly in providing the minimum sample sizes required for a given number of allowed errors.

I'm wondering if anyone can show me a more elegant method or formula to accomplish my goal. I've tried, but I'm not mathematically inclined enough to be able to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, 
Andrew

PS.  If anyone wants to look at a sample workbook that uses a small sample to demonstrate my current method, it can be found on my Dropbox instance [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wahjv6gphx1e7u8/%21%20Accuracy%20and%20Confidence%20-%20Mini.xlsx?dl=0)

**UPDATE:**
Long ago, I validated my Excel workbook with a now defunct online calculator.  The formula used by the calculator was as follows.  I have been unsuccessful in implementing the formula in Excel.
$$P(r \le k) = \sum_{r=0}^k \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} p^r (1-p)^{(n-r)}   $$
Where:
n = Sample Size

p = Proportion Defective

r = Number Defective

$$P(r \le k) = $$probabiliity of k or fewer failures occurring in a test of n  units.

Confidence Level (CL) = $$P(r \le k) $$